# HTML Responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the structure of my HTML and CSS:

```css
/* IMPORTS */


/* COMMON STYLES */
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* PAGE STYLES */
#video-container {
 padding: 0;
 height: 100vh;
}

#video {
 background-color: #6d6;
 height: 65vh;
}

#tv {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 15px;
 height: 50%;
}

#banner {
 height: 5vh;
 background-color: #fff;
}

#ctrl1, #ctrl2 {
 height: 30vh;
}

#ctrl1 {
 background-color: #66d;
}

#ctrl2 {
 background-color: #6dd;
}

#updates-container {
 padding: 0 15px;
 background-color: #d66;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: auto;
}

.update-data {
 height: 35vh;
 border-bottom: dashed 1px #000;
}


.update-data:last-child {
 border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <!-- LEFT SIDE -->
    <div id="video-container" class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="video" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <video autoplay loop id="tv">
                    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/005/571/original/keyboard_02.mp4">
                    <source type="application/ogg" src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/preview2s/000/005/571/original/keyboard_02.ogv">
                    <source type="video/webm" src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/preview3s/000/005/571/original/keyboard_02.webm">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="banner" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">SAMPLE BANNER</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="ctrl1" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6"></div>
            <div id="ctrl2" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- RIGHT SIDE -->
    <div id="updates-container" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="update-data row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                SAMPLE UPDATE 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="update-data row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                SAMPLE UPDATE 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="update-data row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                SAMPLE UPDATE 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="update-data row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                SAMPLE UPDATE 4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my problem is, How would i position the DIV `updates-container` *(the one with the red background)* to the bottom when the browser screen is small ..

Comment: You could use `col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12` for `.video-container` and `col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12` for `.update-container`, So that both of them will take all the columns when it reaches `col-sm`. Unfortunately, I can't see the `.update-container` when I tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<!-- LEFT SIDE -->
<div id="video-container" class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8">
```

to

```
<!-- LEFT SIDE -->
<div id="video-container" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
```

and :

```
<!-- RIGHT SIDE -->
    <div id="updates-container" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
```

to

```
<!-- RIGHT SIDE -->
    <div id="updates-container" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
```

Also,

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

**overflow: hidden** might be a problem on smaller screens, you can use media queries to fix this

Answer (score 0):

since you're using the bootstrap grid lay-out you're able to use some small tricks to achieve what you want.

As you know bootstrap makes use of 12 columns on one `row`. So if we would want to create a full width block we'll use `col-12`.

The `lg, md, sm, xs` refer to the width of the screen.

- `lg` for large screens (≥ 1200px)
- `md` for medium screens (≥ 992px)
- `sm` for small screens (≥ 576px)
- `xs` for extra small screens (< 576px)

[reference](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

You want that the red area will be on a `full-width` new `<row>` on small devices. See the working example below:

```css
/* IMPORTS */


/* COMMON STYLES */
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* PAGE STYLES */
#video-container {
 padding: 0;
 height: 100vh;
}

#video {
 background-color: #6d6;
 height: 65vh;
}

#tv {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 15px;
 height: 50%;
}

#banner {
 height: 5vh;
 background-color: #fff;
}

#ctrl1, #ctrl2 {
 height: 30vh;
}

#ctrl1 {
 background-color: #66d;
}

#ctrl2 {
 background-color: #6dd;
}

#updates-container {
 padding: 0 15px;
 background-color: #d66;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: auto;
}

.update-data {
 height: 35vh;
 border-bottom: dashed 1px #000;
}


.update-data:last-child {
 border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <!-- LEFT SIDE -->
    <div id="video-container" class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="video" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <video autoplay loop id="tv">
                    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/005/571/original/keyboard_02.mp4">
                    <source type="application/ogg" src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/preview2s/000/005/571/original/keyboard_02.ogv">
                    <source type="video/webm" src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/preview3s/000/005/571/original/keyboard_02.webm">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="banner" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">SAMPLE BANNER</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="ctrl1" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6"></div>
            <div id="ctrl2" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- RIGHT SIDE -->
    <div id="updates-container" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="update-data row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                SAMPLE UPDATE 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="update-data row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                SAMPLE UPDATE 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="update-data row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                SAMPLE UPDATE 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="update-data row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                SAMPLE UPDATE 4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By adding the `lg, md, sm, xs` specifics you're able to change the view for each screentype. In this case i've edited the following line:

```
<div id="updates-container" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
```

On the `lg` and `md` view it will act as a sidebar. Where on the `sm` view it'll take up half of the screens width. on the `xs` view each `<div>` inside `updates-container` will have a full width of the screen.

Hope this helps!